# Como fazer com dúvidas que evoluem conforme as respostas são fornecidas?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Hoje eu postei esta pergunta: [Dificuldade em armazenar propriedade em objeto no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3625/dificuldade-em-armazenar-propriedade-em-objeto-no-javascript/3634).

As respostas que obtive inicialmente foram bastante inocentes (na falta de uma palavra melhor) e pouco relacionadas ao problema, até que eu mesmo cheguei a algumas conclusões que optei por incluir em edições (principalmente na segunda edição). Gosto de acreditar que isso não apenas me ajudou a entender melhor o problema como ajudou também o @GustavoRodrigues a oferecer uma resposta mais apropriada. Acontece que olhando para a pergunta agora, eu tenho a sensação de que ali tem na verdade duas perguntas diferentes ainda que relacionadas (pois a "segunda" dúvida surgiu devido à "primeira"): uma sobre uma dificuldade pontual em definir um atributo e outra sobre como funciona o contexto das chamadas em Javascript.

Nesse caso, eu deveria ter adicionado as minhas conclusões como uma resposta ao invés de incluí-las na edição, para evitar de alterar muito a pergunta? Ou então, eu deveria mesmo ter mantido o histórico indicando as edições como eu fiz, pois isso é interessante e suficiente? Ou ainda, eu deveria ter incluido uma resposta minha com as conclusões parciais ao invés de editar a questão?

Eu até pensei em deixar como estava antes da edição 2 e incluir um link para uma nova pergunta a respeito do contexto do `this`, mas fiquei inseguro e simplesmente não o fiz porque achei que a segunda questão poderia ser ampla demais.

Answer (score 5):

Acho que se você chega a uma conclusão que serve de resposta, você **deve** postar uma resposta. Quando faço isso em outros sites do Stack Exchange, eu faço uma breve edição ao final da pergunta para indicar que cheguei por contra própria à conclusão do problema. Mesmo nesses casos, em geral ainda acabo a ver respostas melhores que as minhas próprias.

Já se a pergunta evolui a ponto de que surja uma **nova dúvida**, distinta da original, acredito que o ideal seja deixar a dúvida original ser respondida em sua própria página, e se criar **uma nova pergunta para o novo assunto**. Um dos pontos fortes do formato do Stack Exchange é a objetividade com que os problemas são resolvidos - separar assuntos em perguntas distintas ajuda pessoas que tiveram os mesmos problemas a encontrar a solução mais rápido.

Acredito que no caso da pergunta que você referenciou, seria possível o desmembramento. Uma pergunta se refere à forma de se realizar determinada tarefa em uma linguagem; Outra pergunta é referente a forma como o interpretador da linguagem se comporta em determinado contexto.

Comment: Oi @Renan, obrigado pelos comentários e sugestões.